# Angular/ HTML: After click or press Enter call a function

Tags: html, angular, button, submit

I have a input field and after clicking a button I'm calling a function and get back the right things.
Now I also want that the function is calling after pressing enter.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input (keyup)="searchUser($event)" stype="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suche nach Nachnamen ..."
        aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button (click)="searchForUser()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit"
            id="button-addon2">Suche</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to put my div in a `<form></form>`. Then the whole page is reloading.

Comment: Your button is of type submit hence the reload

Comment: Hi @lisa, the page reloads because the button tries to submit the form. you should bind that form to an ngForm (template driven) or FormGroup(Reactive form). Afterwards listen for the submit event on the form. That way your function gets called when the enter key is clicked and when the button is clicked also

Comment: thanks @YusuffBisiriyu. This is working. I post my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
<form #p="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="searchForUser(u)">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input (keyup)="searchUser($event)" stype="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Suche nach Nachnamen ..." aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Suche</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Explanation: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the input and the button in a form tag, and rather than using a click handler on the button, make it a submit handler on the form element.

```
<form (submit)="searchForUser()">
```

Alternatively, you can remove the type="submit" completely.

Comment: still the same problem. I add my solution as an answer